# php include file globally within a series of functions

Tags: php, function, include

I am writing a template which will have a series of functions and several of them will access the same include file which access a serial of classes. My idea was something like

```
<?php
   require_once("myfile.php");
   $db = new classthing();

 function1(){
   return $db->afunction;
 }

 function2() {

   return $db->anotherfunction;
 }
```

it does not seem to want to work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP functions act in its own scope.
In your case you can go in few ways:

a) passing $db instance as function parameter:

```
 require_once("myfile.php");
 $db = new Classthing();

 function1(Classthing $db){
     return $db->afunction;
 }
 $a = function1($db); // invocation
```

b) using `global` keyword to access variables from global scope:

```
require_once("myfile.php");
   $db = new Classthing();

 function1(){
   global $db;
   return $db->afunction;
 }
 $a = function1(); // invocation
```

Answer (score 0):

$db is a global variable. If you want to access a global variable within a function in PHP you need to declare it with "global". Also, I am not sure what exactly you want to achieve, but if you want to return a method with your function you should use a reference.

Here is how it should work:

```
function &function1(){
global $db;
return $db->afunction;
}
```